# Try: Run with... siempre después de un error ¿cómo solucionarlo?

Tags: depuración

Estoy tratando de ejecutar mi aplicación en Android, pero me aparece el siguiente mensaje siempre después de un error:

"Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
Run with --scan to get full insights."

estoy seguro de que es lo mas sencillo del mundo pero me está costando averiguar como aplicar esa solución

Cualquier ayuda se agradece. Muchas gracias de antemano.

AGREGO ESTO....

What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.

> Could not find method signingConfigs() for arguments [SigningConfig$AgpDecorated_Decorated{name=release, storeFile=/Volumes/TarjetaSd/proyectos flutter/com_apliarte_app/android/app/Volumes/TarjetaSd/nube/Dropbox/android/keystore.jks, storePassword=xxxxxxxx, keyAlias=xxxxx, keyPassword=xxxxxxx, storeType=pkcs12, v1SigningEnabled=true, v2SigningEnabled=true, enableV1Signing=null, enableV2Signing=null, enableV3Signing=null, enableV4Signing=null}] on BuildType$AgpDecorated_Decorated{name=release, debuggable=false, testCoverageEnabled=false, jniDebuggable=false, pseudoLocalesEnabled=false, renderscriptDebuggable=false, renderscriptOptimLevel=3, minifyEnabled=true, zipAlignEnabled=true, signingConfig=null, embedMicroApp=true, mBuildConfigFields={}, mResValues={}, mProguardFiles=[/Volumes/TarjetaSd/proyectos flutter/com_apliarte_app/build/app/intermediates/default_proguard_files/global/proguard-android.txt-7.1.3, /Users/apliarte/Development/flutter/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter_proguard_rules.pro, /Volumes/TarjetaSd/proyectos flutter/com_apliarte_app/android/app/proguard-rules.pro], mConsumerProguardFiles=[], mManifestPlaceholders={}} of type com.android.build.gradle.internal.dsl.BuildType$AgpDecorated.

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 4s

GRACIAS por contestar tan rápido

Comment: Hola, bienvenido a la comunidad. Te invito a hacer el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y leer [¿cómo preguntar?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Además, para poder reproducir tu problema y encontrar una solución fácilmente nos sería de gran ayuda un [ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). ¿Has probado los pasos que se indican en la documentación oficial de Android Studio? https://developer.android.com/studio/debug ¿Ese mensaje te sale en el Logcat o en tu aplicación? Si no compartes más detalles no podremos ayudarte.

Comment: Hola Javier, no creo que haya forma de deshabilitar ese mensaje, pero no tienes que preocuparte, el sistema te indica como hacer para obtener más información sobre el error, lo que te debe preocupar es lo que viene antes... el temido mensaje de error... y la solución a las dos cosas... es no cometer errores, algo que nunca logré.

Comment: HE EDITADO... la publicación, perdón pero entre la dislexia la edad, dormir poco que no me dejan los niños y trabajo cuando estan dormidos, y ahora me he aventurado a actualizar mis apps con flutter lo siento, intentaré hacer mejor las preguntas.

Comment: Aquí explican bien como se usa. https://stackoverflow.com/a/21674403/13419694